# How to use \sloppy for just some references?

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, paragraphs

I’m using XeLaTeX within MiKTeX and also the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package for the literature.

I’ve noticed that my bibliography set using `\printbibliography` is not set with the `\sloppy` option by default, which is quite good in my opinion.

What I would like to be able to do is to make `\sloppy` or `\sloppypar` only those references in the bibliography that actually need it, that means those records which get overfull `\hbox`. I don’t want it to be done automatically but I haven’t found a way to do it even manually. Is this even possible?

Comment: You could try to use the `execute` field in the bib-entry to insert the code (untested as you didn't provide a small example to play around with).

Answer (score 23):

I'd set `\emergencystretch` before `\printbibliography`:

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{8em}
\printbibliography
\endgroup
```

TeX uses `\emergencystretch` only when a paragraph doesn't fit with the usual parameters, so this may solve the problem. Experiment with the value of `\emergencystretch`.

Comment: Worked fine 6em was enough for all my 5 problems though. Start small and expand till it works!

Answer (score 6):

As Ulrike Fischer has hinted: Use the `execute` special field to add `\sloppy` for the respective reference entries.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\displayemergencystretch}{%
  Emergency stretch: \the\emergencystretch
}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  \addspace% ADDED
  \printtext[brackets]{\displayemergencystretch}% ADDED
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  execute = {\sloppy},
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\sloppy

A \verb|\sloppy| paragraph~-- \displayemergencystretch

\fussy

A \verb|\fussy| paragraph~-- \displayemergencystretch

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it actually did not work. No idea why not.

Comment: @josefec +1, I got the same emergencystretch value (which seems good) but the paragraph is not sloppy. I tried with `title = {a very long line with a ve\-rylongwordthatLaTeXwillnotbeabletohyphenate}` instead of `Bravo` and only a `\sloppy\printbibliography` did the job correctly, unfortunately. I guess this is slightly more complicated than just adding `execute = {\sloppy}`...

Answer (score -1):

This isn't 100% a direct answer, but as I just fought through a similar problem in my bibliography, here's my approach.  It uses the `ragged2e` package, which defines a `\RaggedRight` command that still permits hyphenation -- and crucially for me at least, that includes hyphens inside urls (when using the `url` package).  I decided to enable `\RaggedRight` only for `@electronic` items (whose main contents are a short title and a wicked-to-linebreak url), and defined my own .bst file. It's a copy/paste/modify from abbrvnat.bst, and here's the relevant excerpt:

```
FUNCTION {electronic}
{ output.bibitem
  url empty$ 'skip$ { "\begin{FlushLeft}" write$ newline$ } if$
  format.authors output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  year empty$ month empty$ day and and
  'skip$
  {
    new.block
    format.date output 
  }
  if$
  new.block 
  format.url output
  note empty$ 'skip$
  {
    new.block
    note output
  }
  if$
  fin.entry
  url empty$ 'skip$ { "\end{FlushLeft}" write$ newline$ } if$
}
```

.bst files are tricky beasts, but the upshot of this code is, **if** there is a url, then I surround the contents of the entry with a `FlushLeft` environment, which enables `\RaggedRight` on this paragraph -- and only this paragraph.

To use the `execute` field, as @UlrikeFischer suggested, you could redefine `output.bibitem` and `fin.entry` to check for the `execute` field and output it:

```
% in output.bibitem
execute empty$ 'skip$ "\begingroup" execute * write$
% in fin.entry
execute empty$ 'skip$ "\endgroup" write$
```

Then your `execute` field could contain `\RaggedRight` and you'd get the same effect as my code above, but for all .bib items that you annotated.  It's not quite the automatic "overfull hbox" solution, but it might be useful anyway.

Comment: This is a regular `natbib` solution, not `biblatex` which is what @josefec is using.

Comment: @AlanMunn, touche, I missed that key detail...my bad!  I'm not a biblatex user (yet), let alone informed-enough expert, so I can't help there, then.  But maybe the ideas above are helpful for people anyway.

Comment: I consider it wrong to use hyphens in URLs, for the simple reason that `-` can be part of a valid URL, and therefore adding a hyphen can change the URL.

Comment: Have a +1 for your comment and a -1 for your answer (hopefully that cancles each other out ^^)

Comment: FWIW, @SebastianSchmitz, they don't cancel each other, actually -- upvotes on comments don't add reputation points.  It's fine; I don't mind the loss of 2 points ;-)