# Biblatex linebreaks inside \cite

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, line-breaking, biber

I'm currently confronted with some problems regarding linebreaks inside citations. I'm using biblatex with a biber backend.

**config:**

```
\usepackage[hidelinks,breaklinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
style=alphabetic,
natbib=true, 
hyperref=true, 
]{biblatex}
```

Most of the time when I create a citation like this `\cite[354]{reference1}` and it comes to the end of a line a linebreak is inserted just fine:

[image: how it should be]

However, sometimes the linebreak fails. Command is `\cite[270]{reference2}`:

[image: how it is sometimes]

It doesn't seem to be related to the position of the citation within the sentence. I've already seen [some](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228774/linebreak-in-biblatex-citation) [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228842/superfullcite-with-style-alphabetic?lq=1) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27953/linebreak-before-url-with-biblatex-alphabetic?rq=1) but I could not figure out a working solution. Am I missing something?

---

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.54cm, marginparwidth=2.0cm, footskip=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abc.bib}
    @book{xyz,
        title={Iasd},
        author={Kersten, X. and Bjhsdfojgf, A.D. and HBjdsf, J. and Sjkvhds, K.W.},
        year={2013},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
style=alphabetic,
natbib=true, 
hyperref=true, 
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{abc.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed dm nonumlllllllllllll \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 

Pino dfgdfgfdgfgfgfgf sdsdsds den dfgdfgfgfgfgfg eines Datensatzes irreversibel \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

This one could be solved using `margin=2.57cm` but that would cause other linebreaks of the document to fail. Apart from that I would like to obtain my document settings because they come from a unified template. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: That is simply the line breaking algorithm. You cannot break between "S." and "207", and breaking before the page might leave too much space. Can you provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces the issue (with as few lines of code as possible).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It wasn't easy but I finally managed to create an MWE.

Comment: Thank you very much for the MWE! Line breaking is a very sensitive and complex issue. Since LaTeX is very clever and tries very hard, sometimes it is just better to re-word sentences or rearrange what you have written a bit. The first try is probably often the [`microtype`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package which can help in many (but unfortunately not all) cases - in your MWE it helps. Then you could try `\emergencystretch` (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241343/35864) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18505/35864)) - maybe even only locally....

Comment: Thanks a lot @moewe! The `microtype` package removed all ugly linebreaks but your other suggestions work as well. Can't decide for one solution yet but the problem is fixed. If you like, sum it up in an answer. It might be accepted ;)

Comment: Done! Note that I had to retract the idea with a negative `\penalty` in `\postnotedelim`. The required penalty was so negative, it forced line breaks virtually everywhere, which rendered this approach quite useless, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line breaks are a very delicate, fragile and complex matter.
If you have problems with your line breaking I would suggest trying the following solutions in the order listed here.

The package [`microtype`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) can often help with line breaks and other micro-typographic features. It cannot help with all problems, the issue in the MWE it is well able to resolve.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.54cm, marginparwidth=2.0cm, footskip=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{xyz,
        title={Iasd},
        author={Kersten, X. and Bjhsdfojgf, A.D. and HBjdsf, J. and Sjkvhds, K.W.},
        year={2013},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed dm nonumlllllllllllll \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 

Pino dfgdfgfdgfgfgfgf sdsdsds den dfgdfgfgfgfgfg eines Datensatzes irreversibel \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then you can reword your sentences or rearrange your text such that the line breaks look fine afterwards.

If `microtype` cannot help you and you don't want to rearrange your text, you might have to resort to more ad-hoc solutions.

You can allow for additional stretch space via `\emergencystretch`.
You will probably have to experiment with the value, in your MWE

```
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2pt}
```

worked just fine.
See also [What is the meaning of \fussy, \sloppy, \emergencystretch, \tolerance, \hbadness?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241343/35864), [Temporarily increase the limit on space size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52850/35864) and [How to use \sloppy for just some references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18505/35864)

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.54cm, marginparwidth=2.0cm, footskip=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{xyz,
        title={Iasd},
        author={Kersten, X. and Bjhsdfojgf, A.D. and HBjdsf, J. and Sjkvhds, K.W.},
        year={2013},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}    

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{2pt}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed dm nonumlllllllllllll \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 

Pino dfgdfgfdgfgfgfgf sdsdsds den dfgdfgfgfgfgfg eines Datensatzes irreversibel \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The higher `\emergencystretch` can be changed locally with the suggestions in [An environment for setting \emergencystretch locally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84510/35864)

```
\newenvironment{emergency}[1]{%
  \par
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{#1}%
}{%
  \par
}
```

You then wrap the environment `emergency` with a suitable length in the argument around the paragraph having breaking troubles.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.54cm, marginparwidth=2.0cm, footskip=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{xyz,
        title={Iasd},
        author={Kersten, X. and Bjhsdfojgf, A.D. and HBjdsf, J. and Sjkvhds, K.W.},
        year={2013},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber, 
style=alphabetic,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newenvironment{emergency}[1]{%
  \par
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{#1}%
}{%
  \par
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed dm nonumlllllllllllll \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 

\begin{emergency}{1pt}
Pino dfgdfgfdgfgfgfgf sdsdsds den dfgdfgfgfgfgfg eines Datensatzes irreversibel \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
\end{emergency}

Pino dfgdfgfdgfgfgfgf sdsdsds den dfgdfgfgfgfgfg eines Datensatzes irreversibel \cite[270]{xyz}. invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebu. clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 

Lorem \cite[270]{xyz} ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also [Do I have to care about bad boxes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50830/35864). Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a near-equivalent English version of [TeXwelt's  *Was bedeutet underfull/overfull \hbox?* (in German)](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/20/was-bedeutet-underfulloverfull-hbox), but there is the [UK TeX FAQ's *(La)TeX makes overfull lines*](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-overfull.html)